# Is it safe to delete the ./work folder in NiFi in between server restart?

Tags: apache-nifi

How is the ./work folder used by NiFi ?
I see a few sub folders underneath this.

./work/nar
./work/docs
./work/jetty

Is it okay to clean up this folder during restart ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is safe, but deleting work/nar will likely slow down the next start up a little bit since it will have to re-extract every NAR there again, so I'm not sure you would want to do that every single restart.